# Umbraco 7.6.1 Won't Upgrade

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have an Umbraco 7.6.1 site which I'm trying to upgrade to a later version, I'm not sure which version I'm going to yet, but the problem exists no matter the version jump.

The Umbraco project is set up in Visual Code IDE and uses NuGet.

So I go to the projects NuGet package manager and update UmbracoCMS from 7.6.1 to 7.6.2. I don't overwrite files. I've tried overwriting files and checking what it's doing in git, but with no luck either.

All seems well. I then build the project and load up the site in debugging mode. I get asked to log in and pushed to the upgrade page. I then hit continue and shown "Error during installation" instantly. It also tells me to check the logs, which are non-existent.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Please take a look at these steps, these are the steps that I have been following for nearly 5 years now. As long as you follow these steps, you should be able to do your umbraco upgrade. Ignore the downvote as I don't know why somebody did it, instead of upvoting it. Hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762498/whats-the-best-way-to-upgrade-from-umbraco-7-6-to-7-15-1-including-db-upgrade/57770513#57770513

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue I was having I commented out any rewrite rules I was including in my main Web.config and cleared out everything in the bin folder and re-built the solution. That seemed to have done the trick.